# How do you assess which bridge rectifier you would need for your application?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, components, mains

Im curious into how you go about picking a bridge rectifier IC for x application , and what papers i would need to read or be aware of if i wanted to build something to last in an industrial enviroment ?

Is a fuse / bi-TVS and rectifier+bulk cap  enough for most applications regarding protection ?

some appllications off the top of my head

IE: Building IOT
device uses an amp, and the line is 24vac.

IE: Wall charger
device is expected to have a 5A load/ connected to mains

what parameters alone would be applicable to these applications.
[image: Parameters]

looking myself, for the first application,  IF to be 1.5A / Peak reverse 150V / id guess Vf to be as low as possible with respect to cost  / max surge current of 20A since the jump prior to that is 4A

For the second for australia so residential 230V @ 50hz
if of 10A + // Peak reverse id pick around 800V+  // vf same as before  and max surge of 20A+

[image]

I also came across devices like the LT4320, that seem to out preform but have little stock, are devices like these more common place as opposed to the typical rectifier and bulk capacitor configuration ?

Link to selection:
https://au.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/discrete-semiconductors/diodes-rectifiers/bridge-rectifiers/?termination%20style=SMD%2FSMT

Comment: no "paper" you'd need to read. You will need to exactly write down your application's requirements. There's never any "enough for most applications" solution – you need to know what your application needs! For example, both your device examples probably shouldn't contain a bridge rectifier at all, but an step-down switch-mode power supply, and in the case of the wall-charger, definitely one that **must** be isolated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Completely agree, i've opened up a few and had a look inside. obviously mains is another ballpark entirely. The papers im referring to are more in line with regulations or tests IECXXXX so wouldnt that be important to read if selling was a goal?

For the industrial 24VAC where ideally if i were to make a circuit wouldnt the rectifier be a step before some DC regulation since it's already been treated(unsure if thats the right wording) to 24vac in that building ?

Answer (score 0):

All of the parameters listed in the picture are potentially important.  Even the package/case, if miniaturisation is important.  The designer needs to work out the range of acceptable values for each parameter.

Having worked out what parameters are needed, it's then a case of choosing the cheapest and most readily available device that meets that need.  You can find 1N400x series silicon diodes in a wide range of different appliances, because they are extremely cheap.  It doesn't matter if the rectifier chosen is far better than the requirements, if it is cheap.

Many manufacturers these days out-source the problem of designing power supplies by buying them in ready-made from a specialist power supply manufacturer.  Power supplies using a transformer, rectifier and bulk capacitor are very old-fashioned these days, and a bought-in switch mode power supply can be cheaper, smaller and lighter.

Comment: and theyre already certified in most cases as well !
i was just personally interested in making one for no reason in particular.